# Is it possible to create userfriendly urls for pkb2 knowledge articles?

Tags: url

I would like to make my article urls userfriendly.
So In stead of 
/service/articles/FAQ/Mijn-bestelling-is-beschadigd-aangekomen-1449140782464/?
I would like
/service/articles/FAQ/Mijn-bestelling-is-beschadigd-aangekomen

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The link generated depends on the article URL name field .Please check your article URL name field to generate URL as you wish.